# The sup of square of root P which P is a constant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is $\sup\sqrt[p]{2n+1}$  which $p$ is a constant and $ p \geq 1 $.
I just know that the $\lim \sqrt[n]{P(x)}$ and $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is 1.

Comment: It is $0$ if $p <0$ and $\infty$ if $p >0$.

Comment: $p$ is grater than 1 .... How is it posibble? Imagine $p$ is a very big number such as 1000000000

Comment: You said $p$ is a constant. So you have to take sup over $n$ for fixed $p$.